# code not related to events in the event loop for pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game with pygame and have a few doubts about the event loop

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```

Namely, does it run infinitely or does it run for a 60th of a second
and can you put non event operators in the loop
such as:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            check = True
        if check:
            print("Hello")
            check = False
```

Would it print "Hello" every time you click or would it break in some way?

Comment: _would it break in some way?_ - it will raise `NameError` caused by referencing `check` before assignment. _does it run infinitely or does it run for a 60th of a second?_ it runs every frame (`clock.tick(60)` means 60fps or less). _can you put non event operators in the loop?_ yes, but there is no point for doing that, as it will be executed multiple times per frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game loop will run infinitely at a maximum of 60 iterations per second due to `clock.tick(60)`. `tick` is a measure of time in PyGame: `clock.tick(60)` means that for every second at most 60 frames should pass.

Your code seems mostly fine, but you need to initialize `check` before using it:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
check = False  #Initialization

while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            check = True
    if check:
        print("Hello")
        check = False
```

I haven't run it, but I think it should print "Hello" each time you click.